# vuejs object with spaces syntax

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Unfortunately I have to work with an object that has spaces in the labels.

I can loop through the object with the following:

```
v-for="index in $data['wins Lane 1'].player2.pts"
```

"Lane 1" is a variable called "item.lane" I am trying to pass in but I can't figure out the correct syntax.  The following doesn't not work:

```
v-for="index in $data['wins ' + item.lane].player2.pts"
```

Help!

Comment: Can you prepare an example - fiddle or something? The 2nd approach works fine with (somewhat) [simplified demo](http://jsfiddle.net/maL5jfs2/)

Comment: this is [another fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bemg02d8/3/) which works fine also

Comment: Thanks for the examples, it led me to recheck all my code.  The component was being rendered while the data property was undefined.  A simple v-if on the component fixed the issue.  Since it worked with 'wins Lane 1' my assumption was that it was a syntax issue.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it works, you can try using javascript template literals

```
v-for="index in $data[`wins ${item.lane}`].player2.pts"
```

Answer (score -1):

This syntax was correct.

```
v-for="index in $data['wins ' + item.lane].player2.pts"
```

The issue was the component trying to render while item.lane was undefined.